# Why compiling a c++/cli program with /clr:safe option makes methods exported by a referenced dll faster than with /clr option?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, interop, clr

I wrote a simple C# class compiled as a dll assembly with the following command in a Visual Studio developer command prompt window:

**csc /target:library /out:testdll.dll testdll.cs**

Here is the code structure of the C# file ***testdll.cs***:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Test
{
    public class AClass
    {

        AClass()
        {
        }

        private void DoSomething()
        {
           // Something I want to optimize to minimize execution time
           //...
        }

        // Calls the AClass.DoSomething() method 1'000'000 times and displays the 
        // average execution time of the method AClass.DoSomething() in micro-seconds 
        // on the console. 
        public static void Test()
        {
            AClass obj = new AClass();
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            Console.Write("Testing...");
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 1; i<=1000000; i++)
                obj.DoSomething();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.Write("done.");
            Console.WriteLine(" AClass.DoSomething() average execution time is {0}us", 
                              ((float)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I then wrote a very simple C++ stub program simply launching the static AClass.Test() method exported by my C# ***testdll.dll***:

Here is the code of the C++ file ***testcpp.cpp***:

```
#using "testdll.dll"
void main()
{
    Test::AClass::Test();
}
```

If I compile this C++ program with the following command:

**cl /clr testcpp.cpp**

And if I then run the ***testcpp.exe*** program. I get something like that:

**Testing...done. AClass.DoSomething() average execution time is 1.253 us**

Now I compile again my C++ program in safe mode with the following command:

**cl /clr:safe testcpp.cpp**

Note that the dll has not been recompiled ! It was not changed since the first execution !

I run the newly compiled ***testcpp.exe*** program and get the following result:

**Testing...done. AClass.DoSomething() average execution time is 0.612 us**

!!!!!

**Can somebody explain to me why the /clr:safe option of the calling c++ program can change the execution time of the not recompiled dll's AClass.DoSomething() method ???!!!**

Thank you.

Pierre-François Culand

Comment: The code you posted takes a nanosecond to execute, that doesn't help.  I don't see any strong signals when doing something non-trivial in DoSomething(), the generated machine code is *exactly* the same.  Which is of course the way it should be.  Always watch out for the effect the debugger has on the jitter optimizer.  Tools + Options, Debugging, General, untick the "Supress JIT optimization" option.

Comment: 1.253 µs is about twice of 0.612 µs. This could be due to the resolution of your Stopwatch. Perform more work in your method (to get higher values), and check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency(v=vs.110).aspx